# How to prevent a "0" as the first character when typing in input type number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keycode

I want to prevent 0 as the first character. But when I focusout and focusin again, then I add "2" in the first, it still run, I want should not run.

Here is my HTML

```
<input type="number" id="test">
```

My JS

```
$('#test').keypress(function(evt) {
  if (evt.which == "0".charCodeAt(0) && $(this).val().trim() == "") {
  return false;
   }
});
```

Anybody help or suggest what should I do? Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent the user from entering a value that begins with `"0"`? (So `"02"` would not be allowed but `"20"` would be allowed?) Because if so you can't do that by testing just the current keypress because the user may type the `"2"` then move the cursor in front of it and type the `"0"`. (Also they may edit the field without using the keyboard, i.e., by pasting or drag'n'drop.)

Comment: why not change the value you get i think if you parse(parseint for example) in the value the leading zero will be removed

Comment: Hi @nnnnnn yes it was I mean.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `input` event, which also handles pasted values, `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/^0/` to replace all `0` characters found within `.value` of element

```js
$("#test").on("input", function() {
  if (/^0/.test(this.value)) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/^0/, "")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="number" id="test">
```

Comment: Hi @guest271314 that is not what I mean. Because I need only number,

Comment: This gives kind of a weird user experience if the user tries to edit an existing value by entering a zero in the middle, because it moves the cursor to the end of the string. Also, I think the OP wants to allow zeros as long as they're not the first character.

Comment: @nnnnnn _"Also, I think the OP wants to allow zeros as long as they're not the first character."_ Ok. See updated post. Added `^` to beginning of `RegExp`; initially interpreted requirement for no `0` characters to be able to be entered. Question does not appear to indicate only first character that is `0` should not be allowed?

Comment: @dediwibisono See updated post. Added `^` to `RegExp`

Comment: @guest271314 - I wanted to add this edit but it's not long enough! Add `+` after 0 in case multiple zeroes are pasted, like so `this.value = this.value.replace(/^0+/, "")`

Comment: Hi @guest271314 it's better and thank you for your response, but the character like "e", "-", "+" it must disabled.

Comment: What do you mean by "disabled"? The characters "e", "-", "+" should not be allowed at all?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I mean not allowed character like "e", "-", "+" and only number (0-9). Yes I try using Regex  @guest271314

Comment: @dediwibisono Note, requirement _"I mean not allowed character like "e", "-", "+""_ does not appear at original Question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Compare `which` property with the ASCII code of number `0` and return false.

```
if (evt.which === 48) {
  return false;
}
```

**[Check Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/79goqon6/)**

Comment: Hi @Sushanth thank you for the answer. I'm sorry but I want to clear my question. your answer is disabled all "0". I mean "0" is only disabled in the first. When I typing "0" for the next it should be run. I hope you understand my question Thank you :)

Comment: Isn't the OP's code already making this comparison with the `"0".charCodeAt(0)` check?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#test').on("keypress",function (evt) {
   if (this.value.length == 1 && evt.which == 48 )
   {
      evt.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

Comment: You'll be able to type 0 at the beginning if there's already some value (ex. type 77, move caret to the beginning, type 0)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
  if (event.target.value.length == 0 && event.which == 48) {
  return false;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add condition for this block "0" from first character using --> event.target.value.
Here is the following code for block "0" from first character.

**Javascript**.

```
     const handleOnchange =()=>{
       if(event.target.name === "myEvent"){
         event.target.value === event.targe.value.replace(/^0/, "");
      }
    }
```

**HTML**.

```
<input type="number" name="myEvent" id="myEvent" onChange={handleOnchange} />
```